# Bindings vs IBOutlets in Objective-C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iboutlet

I'm going through a simple Objective-C/Cocoa program to try and learn the language and am getting a little confused about how some things are linked from the code I write to the interface builder.

For example, I have a simple NSString:

```
@property (assign) NSString *letters;
```

And in my interface builder, I have a text field and I use the text field's bindings to connect it to letters.

However, the example also has this:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSArrayController *wordsController;
```

In the view I have a table that continuously changes and shows different words and those words are stored in an NSMutableArray.  I suppose I can understand that I just can't bind the array to the the table because there are some more complexities.  So in the Interface Builder I create an Array Controller and bind it to the table.  In the Array Controller's bindings, I bind the Array Controller to the array of words.

I understand that the last thing I have to do is also bind the Array Controller to my NSArrayController object as well.  I don't understand why I do this through the main controller object by making a connection between this outlet and the wordsController.  In the Array Controller's bindings section there's a greyed out option, Content Object, which says "An NSArrayController that the NSArrayController treats as its content."  Why wouldn't I set the binding here?  What is the significance of it being an outlet and why is it different than my NSString letters?

Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. In most cases, the Cocoa bindings would be: table view and table columns are bound to the array controller; array controller is bound to an array. `IBOutlets` are independent of bindings and are used if you need to reference a nib object in code. Maybe you could post your project somewhere for others to take a look at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are confusing bindings and IBOutlets. This is not unreasonable -- it's a lot of Control-dragging of connections and it can be hard to keep clear what's going on. Let me try to explain:

Bindings are a way to let Cocoa handle the mechanics of keeping a model (some collection of data, even something as simple as a single `NSString`) and a view (an object which displays on the screen) in sync. When you "bind" your `NSString` to a text field's `value`, you are asking the framework to communicate changes to the string or the text field "behind the scenes"; your object which owns the string gets notified to change the string's value when the text field changes, and vice versa.*

A similar situation applies to your mutable array, array controller, and table view. You're essentially right about the complications: the mutable array and the table view don't know how to talk to each other; the array controller stands in between and facilitates: ("Okay, tableView wants to know what to put in row *i*. Array, give me your object at index *i*." :) In the past, you would've had to write that code manually, and it looked very similar every time you did so.

That's what the bindings do. They are a way to reduce boilerplate code. The `IBOutlet` to the array controller gives your object a way to send messages to the array controller, if necessary. One simple example of why you might need to do this is to allow a menu item to trigger a method in the array controller; a document object or another controller might handle the action from the menu item and call the appropriate message on the array controller. You can also ask the array controller for its `arrangedObjects` to get, for example, the sorted and filtered version of its content array.

---

<sub>* One side note here is that your `NSString` property should almost certainly use `retain`, not `assign`. The object that contains this variable should be responsible for its memory.</sub>

Comment: One of the most helpful answers I've seen!  Thanks!  And also, about your note on retain vs assign, I'm just starting to learn the differences.  The book I'm using uses assign and says to do that because I'm using garbage collection.

Comment: Garbage collection is the correct answer to that one. Very glad I was helpful; best of luck!